# .net 4.5 & Server 2007

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to run this framework on the server. I know people have done this from what I am seeing around the blogs, but Microsofts site states 2008 servers. From what I understand, its just a minor update of the framework.

Comment: Windows Server 2007 doesn't exist.

Comment: Typo IIS 7. Am I suppose to be getting an option to create an application pool for 4.5. It still shows 4.0

Comment: This was also with the mandatory restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 4.5 version of the framework uses the 4.0 runtime, in the same way that the 3.0 and 3.5 versions used the 2.0 runtime.

That means that for IIS application pools, you won't see a 4.5 version option - choose 4.0

Comment: I'm not even seeing an option in Visual Studio for 4.5. Im running 2010

Comment: I also do know its installed because when i rerun the bootstrapper it asks if i want to repair

Comment: @IsabelleHarms 2010 can't do 4.5. You need 2012